# In JDO (AppEngine), after persisting an object, how can i get the key of that particular object?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, persistence, jdo, object-persistence

When I persist an object to the datastore, when (and how) can I get the key of that particular object that I just persisted? So for example, if I have:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Employee {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;
...
}
```

The Query class:

```
public class EmployeeQuery {
    // Persist a single Employee
    public void persistEmployee(Employee e) {
    // 1. Can I get the id at this point?
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        pm.makePersistent(e);
        // 2. Can I get the id at this point?
    } 
    finally {
        pm.close();
        // 3. Can I get the id at this point?
    }
    }
...
}
```

The PersistenceManager and PMF information can be found here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/overview.html#Getting_a_PersistenceManager_Instance

As mentioned above, where in the mentioned areas (1, 2 or 3) can I get the auto-generated id of that particular object? Also, how can I get the id of that specific object? Any suggestions of how to do this efficiently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the key in **Point 2**, once the object is persisted.  **Point 1** is too early and **Point 3** is also called when an exception occurs, so you can not guarantee to have a generated key.

As the [official docs](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html#Keys) say : *"The long key field of an instance is populated when the instance is saved."*

Comment: Can I just call my own function "getId()" from my Employee class?